# Grub isn't loading on my SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, debian, multi-boot, grub

I have a bad problem. I have **two** storage devices installed on my laptop!(**SSD & Hard Drive**). I have installed Windows 10 **lately** on **SSD**, but now I want to install Kali Linux on my **HDD**. I installed it successfully(On **Hard Drive**). **first time**, I installed kali boot loader on **Hard Drive**, It doesn't load(I uninstalled kali completely), but **second time** I installed Grub boot loader on **SSD(where is my windows 10 & windows boot loader installed.)** It's working, but there is an other problem. The problem is when I boot my device on **SSD** Grub boot loader doesn't working well, and it shows an **error: No such device found**, but when I boot on **Hard Drive** it's working well.(I need to change the boot device with key F12 each time.) becuase of this problem I changed my boot order from diskette to hard drive, but it doesn't have effects(I need to change boot order with key F12 every single time.)

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [Kali isn't meant to be installed](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), in particular not so by inexperienced users. If you just want to use Linux, pick a distribution aimed at general usage, not a highly specialized one like Kali. If you want to use Kali for its intended purpose, boot it from USB like you're supposed to.

---

It's hard to guess what exactly is going on because we don't know if you're using BIOS or EFI boot, but my guess is all your bootloader files are on HDD and it obviously cannot be loaded when it's missing.

A relatively simple workaround *if you're using EFI boot* would be to install rEFInd, which will fit on the EFI System Partition (most likely on SSD) and let you choose which bootloader to use: GRUB (Linux) or bootmgr (Windows). I'm intentionally leaving out details on how to do that because if you can't figure it out yourself, you'll just hit more obstacles down the road which will eventually guide you towards a distro actually designed for general use.

Comment: I'm completely confused man! My system using BIOS, and my windows & Kali boot files are on each place, but system files path are different. 
Thanks for answer. If you can please help me.

Comment: Do you have `/boot` on both disks? If not, that's the culprit. GRUB doesn't fit in MBR or boot sector, there's only a tiny piece of code there to load the rest of it from another partition. You'd also probably have to make sure that both `/boot` partitions have identical IDs.

Comment: Thanks a million for help bro! I'm going to delete Kali and reinstall it on **SSD**.(dual boot with win 10)

Comment: Please, please read the first paragraph again.